# How can i save multiple click counters in localstorage?

Tags: javascript

I have several counters, how can I store all values in the store? And is this even possible in this example?

I created a code snippet here:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.dataset.counter != undefined) {
    event.target.value++;
  }
});
```

```html
Counter: <input type="button" value="1" data-counter> 
Another counter: <input type="button" value="2" data-counter> 
And another counter: <input type="button" value="2" data-counter>
```

Comment: Do you want to cache all the counts after clicking once, or to cache the count of the current click?

Comment: I want to cache current numbers of click to localstorage

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.dataset.counter != undefined) {
    event.target.value++;
    window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.name, event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
Counter: <input type="button" value="1" name="counter1" data-counter> Another counter: <input type="button" value="2" name="counter2" data-counter> And another counter: <input type="button" value="2" name="counter3" data-counter>
```

Use `localStorage.setItem` function to cache it when you clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your buttons IDs and use an object to store the values as key value pairs (where each key is an ID corresponding to a button). Then you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` when storing and retrieving that object from the `localStorage`.

As `localStorage` doesn't work here in stack snippets, [see this codepen](https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/BaaJbqE) for a working example.

```js
var clickStore = window.localStorage.getItem('clickStore') || '{}';
clickStore = JSON.parse(clickStore);

console.log(clickStore);

Object.entries(clickStore).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  var btn = document.querySelector(`#${key}`);
  if (btn) {
    btn.value = value;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.dataset.counter != undefined) {
    event.target.value++;
  }
  clickStore[event.target.id] = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(clickStore));
  window.localStorage.setItem('clickStore', JSON.stringify(clickStore));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can i use this when instead id="counter1" and id="counter2" i got same class with this buttons?

Comment: You need some kind of unique reference, otherwise you'll have trouble assigning the value to each button. The number of buttons might change in the future, so the index of each element based on just the class or data attribute won't work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to set up  an object in memory and then to update that object whenever you update any of the counters.

**Working Example:**

```js
// Grab dataCounter Buttons
const dataCount = document.getElementsByClassName('data-count')[0];
const dataCounters = [... document.querySelectorAll('[data-counter]')];

// Initialise dataCountObject
let dataCountObject = {};
dataCounters.forEach((dataCounter, i) => {
  dataCountObject['dataCounter' + i] = parseInt(dataCounter.value);
});
console.log(dataCountObject);

// Increment both dataCounter and dataCountObject
const incrementCount = (event) => {

  if (event.target.dataset.counter != undefined) {
  
    let index = dataCounters.indexOf(event.target);
    dataCountObject['dataCounter' + index]++;
    event.target.value++;
    console.log(dataCountObject);
  }
}

// Attach Event Listener to dataCount
dataCount.addEventListener('click', incrementCount, false);
```

```html
<form class="data-count">
<label>Counter: <input type="button" value="1" data-counter></label>
<label>Another counter: <input type="button" value="2" data-counter> </label>
<label>And another counter: <input type="button" value="2" data-counter></label>
</form>
```

**Then**, if at any time you want to save to `localStorage` you can serialize the object into a string using:

```
let dataCountJSON = JSON.stringify(dataCountObject);
```

and then you can add the JSON string to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('dataCount', 'dataCountJSON');
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but i don't know how to implement localstorage into this code...

Comment: See the last line of the answer above. It's that simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, saving data after refreshing the page does not work for me...

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome... Here is a code [link](https://codepen.io/ultimatejupiter/pen/wvvpVBw)